# Impala: error while adding variable in query

Tags: variables, impala

I tried to set a variable in impala query, but I am getting the following error. I dont know how to solve it.

```
set var:id = "it"
select * 
from prs_nafisa.rfm_data 
where id=${VAR:id};
```

---

```
SQL Error [500051] [HY000]: [Cloudera][ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, errorMessage:ParseException: Syntax error in line 1:
set var:id = "it"
       ^
Encountered: :
Expected: ADD, ALTER, AND, ARRAY, AS, ASC, BETWEEN, BIGINT, BINARY, BLOCK_SIZE, BOOLEAN, CACHED, CASCADE, CHANGE, CHAR, COMMENT, COMPRESSION, CROSS, DATE, DATETIME, DECIMAL, DEFAULT, DESC, DIV, REAL, DROP, ELSE, ENCODING, END, EXCEPT, FLOAT, FOLLOWING, FOR, FROM, FULL, GROUP, IGNORE, HAVING, ILIKE, IN, INNER, INTEGER, INTERSECT, IREGEXP, IS, JOIN, LEFT, LIKE, LIMIT, LOCATION, ||, MANAGEDLOCATION, MAP, MINUS, NOT, NULL, NULLS, OFFSET, ON, OR, ORDER, PARTITION, PARTITIONED, PRECEDING, PRIMARY, PURGE, RANGE, RECOVER, REGEXP, RENAME, REPLACE, RESTRICT, RIGHT, RLIKE, ROW, ROWS, SELECT, SET, SMALLINT, SORT, STORED, STRAIGHT_JOIN, STRING, STRUCT, TABLESAMPLE, TBLPROPERTIES, THEN, TIMESTAMP, TINYINT, TO, UNCACHED, UNION, UNSET, USING, VALUES, VARCHAR, WHEN, WHERE, WITH, COMMA, IDENTIFIER

CAUSED BY: Exception: Syntax error
), Query: set var:id = "it"
select * from prs_nafisa.rfm_data where id="it".
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it like this

```
$ impala-shell --quiet --var=vid="it"
[impala] > select * from prs_nafisa.rfm_data where id=${var:vid};
```